# Firebase (with react native) HTTPS function doesn't receive parameters

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, react-native-ios

I'm using React native with Firebase. I deployed a function (without query params) and I'm able to call it without problems from my iPhone. When I add parameters, I'm able to run it only on my browser, but on my phone the parameters are undefined.

Firebase function

```
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => { 
    const searchQuery = request.query.search;
    response.status(200).send({data:searchQuery});    
});
```

Client App

```
const testFunction = functions.httpsCallable('testFunction');
testFunction({search: "anything"})
```

I'm suspecting that this is a bug in either Firebase SDK, React Native's translation to iOS or hopefully a problem in my code, what could be the problem?

Comment: where you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

To call firebase functions from app, do not use `onRequest`; use `onCall`. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web-version-9_2) for detailed implementation on both server and client side.

This is also mentioned in the [doc](https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage#calling-an-endpoint) of `react-native-firebase`, but the use of `onCall` is not emphasized (I think it should be highlighted to avoid confusion).

That said, it is possible to call an `onRequest` function from app, but the parameters are not under `request.query`, but under `request.body.data`. For example, in OP's scenario, the firebase function would be

```js
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => { 
  const searchQuery = request.body.data.search; // param is not in query
  response.status(200).send({data:searchQuery});    
});
```

However, calling `onRequest` from app is not recommended, because the success or error message sent back to the client cannot be properly handled by `react-native-firebase`. Thus, the best practice is to use `onCall`.